# When testing a REST Service with SOAPUI is there a way to read the json message body from text file?

Tags: json, rest, soapui

I am working with REST APIs. I have to copy and paste the `JSON` payload into the text box of the test step every time while testing. I want to change the test or try a new test. With what I am testing this happens rather often.This is for use in a program that is user information, so the user changes every time.

Question:

Is there a way to set it up so that instead of having to change that text body in the test step, can I make it so that the text is read from a text file instead? Thus allowing me to just bring in a new text file when I want to run a new test, instead of changing all the test steps.

Answer (score 0):

add something like this to your request payload:

```
${= new File('C:/Users/myUsername/Desktop/myfile.txt').text}
```

please let me know if that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you wanted to bring in automated tests for the REST APIs that you have, using `SOAPUI` tool. In short, yes, it is possible to automate the tests. But, slightly different than you thought or more elegant way.

**Going into little more details:**

From the description, it appears that you imported the `swagger definition` or `wadl` file into `SoapUI`. Modifying the data in the request editor and testing the services. Of course, this is the procedure most of the users do when started using SoapUI. Each time modify the request by hand when a new test is to be executed.

After passing through it for some time, people realize it is monotonous and start finding alternative ways to reduce the effort or some kind of automation, like you came up with the question.

**How it is done:**

SoapUI allows its users to create test cases and be able to run those cases with out modifying them any time later. This is the recommended than what you thought.

Here is the way to design the tests. It is hierarchical.

`Project -> Test Suite -> Test Case -> Test Step`

In the above hierarchy, you can have multiple of test suites, test cases and steps. It is recommended to have the test cases independent of other test cases.

Design your test cases in such a way that, even if multiple (rest/soap/jdbc/groovy and other type of test step) calls to be made and pass the data between the steps(output of one step to input of the following step etc), so that a test can be completed end to end without manual intervention.

[image: Test Hierarchy]

You can find more details in the [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html) in this regard. You may also find there lot more information if you haven't gone through soapui's documentation.

No more editing of the text. This is even avoids like you mentioning, load from file(there also you need to change the file name again and again for different tests). Because, each request goes into a test case and that stays there for later, you have a relevant name for the test case and description as well.

This is all one time effort for you or your team. Then you should be able to run the project easily with hassle free.

Good luck.